# Making a list of all my workers from my sub groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have a class group that has a list of sub groups ,any sub group has a list of workers or a list of sub groups,i want to create a list of all my workers

python says :"TypeError: get_workers() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

how can I send one group at a time?

```
class Group:
    def __init__(self, group_name, group_description, parent_group, sub_groups, list_of_workers ):
        self.group_name = group_name
        self.group_description = group_description
        self.parent_group = parent_group
        self.sub_groups = sub_groups  # either...
        self.list_of_workers = list_of_workers  # or

    def get_workers(self):

        if self.list_of_workers:
            return(self.list_of_workers)
        else:
           return [self.get_workers(x) for x in self.sub_groups]


group_a = Group("group a", "the best group", "", ["group_b", "group_c"], "")
group_b = Group("group b", "the best group", "", [], ["adi", "judy"])
group_c = Group("group c", "the best group", "", [], ["avi", "sam"])


print(group_a.get_workers())
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to find all my workers from all of my sub groups

Comment: And what is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: I dont know how to do it,the "else" part dont work

Comment: What do you mean by 'the "else" part dont work"? Do you get an error? Are you aware that one part *prints* a list, while the other *returns* a list?

Comment: Please include the full traceback. In specific, tell us how you call ``get_workers``. See the [mcve] and [ask] pages how to best help us help you.

Comment: yes :TypeError: get_workers() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: What do you expect ``self.get_workers(x)`` to *mean*? ``Group.get_workers`` does not take arguments other than the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it is: You want Group(s) that HAVE other Group(s) as 'sub_groups'. Each Group optionally has a list of workers. i.e.

```
class Group:
  parent_group: Group
  sub_groups: List[Group]
  list_of_workers: List[str]
```

Now, the solution here works on the objects of these groups (e.g. group_b). Take each group(object) at a time, and find it's workers. As a base case, if there are no sub-groups, print the list of workers. This all happens in the return part of that else.

This is the whole code, edited so you can reference it:

```
class Group:
def __init__(self, group_name, group_description, parent_group, sub_groups, list_of_workers ):
    self.group_name = group_name
    self.group_description = group_description
    self.parent_group = parent_group
    self.sub_groups = sub_groups  # either...
    self.list_of_workers = list_of_workers  # or

def get_workers(self):

    if self.list_of_workers:
        print(self.list_of_workers)
    else:
       return [group.get_workers() for group in self.sub_groups]


group_b = Group("group b", "the best group", "", [], ["adi", "judy"])
group_c = Group("group c", "the best group", "", [], ["avi", "sam"])
group_a = Group("group a", "the best group", "", [group_b, group_c], "")


group_a.get_workers()
```

On an end note, please use types if you don't want that silly confusion. You were earlier referencing strings and not objects.

Comment: look at the way the instances of Group are initialized and referenced. your error is because you are trying to call a string of the sub-group and not an instance of sub-group

Comment: Happy to help. Seems you are learning python right now. SoloLearn would be a great way to start out the basics.